# Virtual Host in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like to set up [Polr Project](http://polr.me/), which is essentially a self-hosted URL shortener, on my hosting. In the [installation guide](https://docs.polr.me/en/latest/user-guide/installation/) it says that I need to set up a virtual host in `httpd-vhosts.conf`. I don't have access to that file so I've got no idea on how to get it to work. I have seen some blog posts about how to do something like this but it doesn't seem to help.

Virtual Host Snippet:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/polr/public"
    <Directory "/var/www/polr/public">
        Require all granted
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried this (but it failed):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} MY_DOMAIN.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot setup a virtual host in .htaccess, as can be seen from the [`<VirtualHost>`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#virtualhost) directive

> Context:   server config

But there's also no need to setup a virtual host, since your web hosting provider already did so.

You need only to install Polr in the document root as described and you're done.

The rewrite rule can be simplified to

```
RewriteRule !^public$ /public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

If you have installed it in some subdirectory, e.g. `polr`, the rule would be

```
RewriteRule !^polr/public$ /polr/public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```